# Is it possible to downscale (actually resize) an image before displaying it and loading the original into RAM?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser, browser-cache

I'm building an Electron app (Chrome + Node.js) which goal is to display all the images of a specified folder.

It's an app, so all the images are already on the disk, no need to download anything.

### Problem:

I need it to display all the images as `64x64` thumbnails, but since they are getting loaded as `<img>` elements, the original images are getting loaded into RAM and only after that CSS "resizes" them to `width: 64px; height: 64px`, but it's not really, it still holds the original images in the RAM, so displaying 300 images (1mb- 20mb) takes ~3.5 GB of RAM.

### Question:

So, I was wondering if there are any simpler ways to just get that `64x64` thumbnail of an image and display that instead of the original on the webpage?

Would that be even possible to make the browser to downscale (actually resize images to 64x64) before displaying them (meaning before loading them into RAM)?

### Tried:

I tried using `<canvas>` instead of `<img>` but it makes the app laggy on scroll because it's quite computationally intensive (~0.1ms / image). I wanted to send it over to a web worker, but couldn't do it.

// I'm using vue.js there

```
// THIS TAG IS INSIDE A V-FOR LOOP SO A CANVAS TAG IS CREATED FOR EACH ITEM IN THE LIST
<canvas :id="'item-' + props.index"> 
  {{drawThumbnails(props.item.path, props.index)}} 
</canvas> 

drawThumbnails (path, canvasId) {
  console.time('draw time')
  var image = new Image(); 
  image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    canvas.width = 64;
    canvas.height = 64;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, 64, 64);
  }
  image.src = path
  console.timeEnd('draw time')
}
```

Another way I figured I could do this is to resize images to `64x64` with `jimp` and save them to disk. It's quite slow but I can send this job to another core using a web worker

Comment: You can make any size copies of an image on the flight as the request is being processed. https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: The classic best practice would be to make actual thumbnails hosted on your server so that you do not download 20mb per pic... It's simple and it works.
If you perform any resizing per request, your server will be down within an hour probably.

Comment: It would be bad practice to have the browser load the original. Generate different versions on demand, cache them on the server and only send the one to the browser that's needed. Client side caching will be taken care of by the browser, don't worry about that. Maybe use ETag and/or If-Modified-Since headers.

Comment: _“Would that be even possible to make the browser to downscale (actually resize images to 64x64) before displaying them (meaning before loading them into RAM)?”_ - it needs to unpack the original image first, before there even _is_ something to downscale. Unless you expect it to do that on a piece of paper or something, of course that means RAM.

Comment: @sjahan it's an app, all the images are located on the local disk

Comment: Not hard to find bulk image processing desktop apps to do it once without needing to write code yourself...assuming you aren't having user add images in your electron app

Comment: @sjahan, it's probably not too wise to guess what would cause a server to go down without knowing the resources. Not sure if you noticed but nowadays server can be really strong.

Comment: @Un1 it's an app, but an Electron one, so it's basically a browser!

Comment: @marekful thanks for the suggestion, but how do you resize an image with it? Do you just run `ffmpeg('/test/image.png).size(64x64)`? Wouldn't you then have to also save it to disk first?

Comment: @marekful True, although, I'd sleep better at night if my server was heavily used and if I had thumbnails instead of pic resizing on each picture request. Static hosting VS working on 20MB pictures... That could add some overhead.

Comment: @sjahan well, there's no server involved whatsoever, it's just an app that displays local images. The problem is it loads the original images into RAM, while I only need it to load the thumbnail images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to not load the original image is to have the resized thumbnail saved to disk as well and load it instead.

This then depends on the fact where these images come from.

If they are created by you and pre-packaged with the app you can do the resizing yourself and package two versions of each image (e.g. `myimage_500x500.png` and `myimage_64x64.png`).

If the images are created by the app, i.e. the app is running on a user's PC, gets image data from some source and writes it to disk, then it can also create the thumbnail and save it as well. A good utility for that would be [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp):

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');

const imageBuffer = getImage() // Data from some source

fs.writeFile('image.png', imageBuffer, (err) => {
  if (err) return callback(err)

  sharp(originalImageBuffer)
    .resize(64, 64)
    .toFile('image_64x64.png', callback);
});
```

If the image is on the user's hard drive but has not been placed there by the app (i.e. your simply accessing existing folders), then you will need to do the above resizing as well, but triggered by some other event. E.g. when an image is first displayed or you check periodically for new images.

---

There is also one way to not have to store a thumbnail on disk but also not keep the big image loaded while it's displayed.
If you add and `express` app or something similar, you can have your `<img>` tags request their images from a route handled by express which then loads the image from disk and does the resizing with sharp on the fly.

The big image would be garbage collected once the request is done and the frontend only shows the small thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks like I cannot escape saving thumbnails to disk. I thought maybe there's a way to actually resize the images with CSS instead of down-scaling the original images

Comment: I think I now got what difference you were talking about with "actually resize" and "down-scaling". I've added an additional section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the idea about express server! I figured I can just pass image paths and generate thumbnails using `sharp` directly inside a function and only then create the `<img>` with the thumbnails, so that it never actually display the original image